# Python For Loop enumerate control

Tags: python-3.x

Hello I Have This Code

```
loss = list(range(1,10))

lists_fru = ['apple','banana','strawberry','erdberry','mango']

for index ,i in enumerate(loss):

    if i > len(lists_fru):
        print('larg')
        
    else:
        print(lists_fru[index])
```

The Resul Of It

```
apple                                                                                                                                                                                
banana                                                                                                                                                                               
strawberry                                                                                                                                                                           
erdberry                                                                                                                                                                             
mango                                                                                                                                                                                
larg                                                                                                                                                                                 
larg                                                                                                                                                                                 
larg                                                                                                                                                                                 
larg
```

What I'm Looking For Or What I'm Trying To Do

I Wanna when the list_fru end to complete the loop from the begining

Like This

```
apple                                                                                                                                                                                
banana                                                                                                                                                                               
strawberry                                                                                                                                                                           
erdberry                                                                                                                                                                             
mango                                                                                                                                                                                
apple                                                                                                                                                                                 
banana                                                                                                                                                                                 
strawberry                                                                                                                                                                                 
erdberry
```

like this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do what you want using the modulo operator, %.

```
loss = list(range(1,10))

lists_fru = ['apple','banana','strawberry','erdberry','mango']

for index ,i in enumerate(loss):
   print(lists_fru[index % len(lists_fru)])
```

Comment: i think in this method `enumerate` is useless.

Comment: @GiorgiImerlishvili You are probably right, but if you don't use enumerate the output doesn't match what's expected/wanted.

Comment: I think OP only used `enumerate` because he couldn't think of a better way to tackle this problem. In your solution it is not needed anymore